# How to find a specific key and add values using vector or map?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a program in which I want to create a **STL** which could hold the details of each `account_num`, along with its `spend`. In other word, two values simultaneously.

So, to get details. I have a `get_details` **function**, its job is to read the details one by one from a **file** *(which stores the values)* and get those values of `account_num`, and their corresponding `spend` and save them into **STL** we made.

**And,** if the `account_num` value **already exist**, then add its **new** `spend` value to its **previous** `spend` value.

**Example:**

Suppose, the file contains the data as an input to the program:

```
account_num         spend
1001                 100  
1001                 200  
1002                 200  
1001                 400  
1002                 100   
1001                 300     
1002                 500
```

And, I want the **output** in the form of **vector** or **map** having the values given below:

```
1001                 1000  
1002                 800
```

Can any one suggest me how to proceed on this

Comment: You're gonna create a STL? Good luck, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if my understanding of your problem is ok. Probably you can create a structure (or class, in C++ this is the same thing except C++ has private member by default) like

```
struct element 
{
    element(unsigned long account, unsigned long spent)
        : m_account(account)
        , m_spent(spent)
    { }

    // copy constructor should be declared too !

private:
    unsigned long m_account;
    unsigned long m_spent;
}
typedef std::list<element> ListOfElement;
```

usage:

```
ListOfElement elementList;
elementList.push_back(element(1001, 100));
elementList.push_back(element(1001, 200));
...
```

Next, browse this list and populate your vector.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming that you are familiar with **map** container.

Now, have a look at the code:

```
void get_details(); 
void display();
map <int , int> M; /* Global map is declared with 'account_num' as key 
                      and 'spend' as its value */   
int main() {
    // do something 
    get_details();   /* call the function */
    display();       /* display the final map */
    // do something
    return 0;
}

void get_details() {
    /* first, start reading from the file which stores the data  */ 
    int account_num;
    int spend;

    while(/* keep on reading the file until EOF is reached */) {

        /*  I'm considering that you are able to read from your file 
            properly and on each iteration we get new values of account_num
            and its spend */

        /*  Now, Look for the account_num value into the map and do the
            following operation */

            M[account_num] += spend;   /* Add the new value if the previous
                                          value already exist or create new
                                          entry with new pair of account_num
                                          and spend */
    }
}

void display() {
    map <int, int> :: iterator it = M.begin();

    for(; it != M.end(); it++) {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }
}
```

Still, having difficulties to understand. comments most welcome.

Comment: This: `for(; it != M.end(); it++)` is exactly what a `map` lets you *avoid*. Don't do it.

Comment: Thank you... i am  writing the code as you suggested.if i got any doubt i will ask you...

Comment: Hi...My requirements got changed and the key values is account_num but instead of spend i should you a structure which contain 3 values spend1,spend2,spend3.. i crated a map and inserted the values sucessfully but i am facing difficulty while updating..can you please suggest me how to update the structure

Comment: do me a favour **explain** it to me using proper example or you could create a new question for that and let me know when you are done because i didn't get anything from your last comment

Answer (score 0):

For this task, a `map` or an `unordered_map` would be a reasonable choice. Applicable code would look something like this:

```
std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
std::map<int, int> values;
int a, b;

std::string ignore;
std::getline(infile, ignore); // read and ignore the initial `account_num spend` line
while (infile >> a >> b)
    values[a] += b;
for (auto const &v : values)
    std::cout << v.first << "\t" << v.second << "\n";
```

Result from your sample data:

```
1001    1000
1002    800
```